# MySQL: Adding connections between people

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table "People" (ID, Name)

```
1, George
2, Nick
3, John
4, Paul
```

Each customer can be connected to another customer (just for reference)
For example George is connected with Paul

So I create a new table PeopleConnections (PeopleConnectID, PeopleID, ConnectedID)

and I add the relations between people

```
1, 1, 4 (George with Paul)
1, 2, 3 (Nick with John)
1, 2, 4 (Nick with Paul)
```

I need to display all relations inside the record view gui. So

- Nick must display: `John, Paul`
- Paul must display: `George, Nick`
- John must display: `Nick`

Is that the correct design to handle this?
What foreign keys should I add?

Answer (score 1):

It's a `many-to-many` relationship and it's a correct design, in my opinion. Your foreign keys should be your `ID` from `People` table. You already answered yourself in that part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your design is generally appropriate. You should place foreign key constraints on PeopleConnections.PeopleID and PeopleConnections.ConnectedID. Both of those should reference People.PeopleID.

You may also wish to place a unique constraint on the aggregate of PeopleConnections.PeopleID and PeopleConnections.ConnectedID, to prevent duplicate relations.